# Update 2sxc application for dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke-module, 2sxc

I create the app for 2sxc and install on server. Now I create the updated version on my local computer and I am interested how to do proper update of this app on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now this cannot be automated, since both source and target can easily change, and "merging" this is something that could be more assisted, but probably never fully automated.